# Mysql maintaing Stock with respect to color and size

Tags: mysql, inventory, stock

I am developing stock inventory for Bicycles. 
I stored `Cycles cid,title, desc etc`, in CYCLE table, and another `STOCK(sid,cid,qty)` for storing stock.
Now i cam to know that Bicycles can have many colors(Black, Red, Orange etc.) AND sizes.
I am confused about storing Stock with respect to Size and Color.

I Modified the STOCK Table

```
STOCK(sid,cid,qty,color,size).
```

e.g.

```
 1,101,12,1,null for Red Color 
 1,101,12,2,null for Green Color
```

......  (6 records for same cycle with respect to color as there can be 6 colors)
PLUS
Size medium,Large,Small (3 records for same cycle with respect to size)
1,101,12,null,medium - for Medium size 
1,101,12,null,Small  - for Small size 
1,101,12,null,Large  - for Large size

Total 9 records for 1 Cycle product.

I have another design in mind for stock 
STOCK(sid,cid,qty,red,green,blue,orange,cyan,yellow,medium,Large,Small)
and 1 single record in stock.
1,101,0,0,1,3,5,6,3,0,7

My question is,
Is this right way to maintain a stock, or i can improve.
If you can help to fine tune, i will greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design should be like this:

Cycle table: only 'properties' of the cycle
CID, COLOR, SIZE, PRICE etc

You'll set your size to "SMALL", "MEDIUM" etc
You'll set your color to "RED", "GREEN" etc

Stock table: only maintain the quantity & related details
ID, CID, QTY, DATE_OF_ARRIVAL_OF_SHIPMENT etc

So now, each row in the Cycle table identifies a 'type' of cycle, and each row in the stock table identifies some cycles in stock.

This is good because now, if you have to add another color / size, you only need to create another row in your table, not modify your structure. Also, now you can write simple queries for all your characteristics (e.g. how many cycles of red color across all sizes are in stock?)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have some question regarding your answer: 1) Putting color and size will create duplication in CYCLE Table. can we minimize this redundancy?  As in my design a Cycle information is stored once. i am thinking of distributing Stock or Cycle table, so redundancy can be eliminated. Waiting for your further opinion, guidance..

Comment: Did not understand - each cycle type has a specific color, and a specific size, right? We are making one entry for each type of cycle. In the stock table, we refer to this entry, and store the number of cycles in stock. Where is data duplicated?

Comment: I carefully read your staments, but i think i misunderstand some where. Please check if i store CYCLE(cid,title,desc,color,size) for "Mountain Bike", it can be CYCLE(1,'Mountain Bike', 'desc','RED','Small'),CYCLE(2,'Mountain Bike', 'desc','RED','Medium'), CYCLE(1,'Mountain Bike', 'any desc','RED','Large'), Here Title and Description repeat for Each record, Sorry if i could not Got You.

Comment: I think we can split cycle, in CYCLE(cid, title, desc,....) For common attributes. And Cycle_Detail (detailId,cid,color,size,...).